# Python MQTT example code get some wrong

Tags: python, mqtt

Here is a code i found

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
   client.subscribe("IOT_NEAT_TOPIC01")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
   print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("mqtt.phodal.com", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

The code what i understand is to connect to the official testing website "mqtt.phodal.com". But it can't work, and the error message shows the error in this line `client.connect("mqtt.phodal.com", 1883, 60)` on my python cose. Then, i posted the address on the browser, it appeared "502 Bad Gateway" which also shows cannot connect the website.I am wondering how to fix this problem? Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: Edit the question and add the full error message from this code. The error from the browser just means that there may be a problem with a web server also running on that machine. Also are you sure that a broker is running on that machine and port? When I try and test I get `Connection refused`

Comment: it's work, when i used "test.mosquitto.org" instead of  "mqtt.phodal.com".

Comment: Then the problem is definitely with `mqtt.phodal.com`

Answer (score 0):

if there is any `username` and `password` for `mqtt` you should provide like :

```
client.username_pw_set('username', 'password')
```